# UIActivity for sharing vCard

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

Been a while since I had to deal with *AddressBook framework*.

I am wondering if there is a way to get some "Add to Addressbook" functionality for free when setting `UIActivityViewController.activityItems` to a vCard with something like:

```
    let vCardString = [
        "BEGIN:VCARD",
        "VERSION:3.0",
        "N:Gump;Forrest",
        "FN:Forrest Gump",
        "ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.",
        "TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-1212",
        "END:VCARD"
        ].joinWithSeparator("\n")

    let vCardData = vCardString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let vCardActivity = NSItemProvider(item: vCardData, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeVCard as String)

    // URL, test,
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [vCardActivity], applicationActivities: activities)
```

I want to circumvent going the long way round, especially when supporting iOS 8 and 9:  With *AddressBook* and *Contacts framework* I would create a person, request permission and present the view controller.

Is there a shorter way, if I "just" want to provide a way to add or share a contact via `UIActivityViewController` ?

**Edit**: The above code does not work, speaking of no corresponding `iOS` activity for the system's contacts is shown. Evernote takes up and shows an activity with correct name. When added to evernote, the vCard is shown in a note with correct details.

Comment: @Hiren Dhamecha: Little over edited? Sorry but, why are you Code Highlighting all those things? "Add to Addressbook" is neither code nor an official term. "iOS 8 and 9" too. And iOS itself in backticks? Regarding the 3 mods that accepted the changes: ???.

Comment: No mods involved in this, it's a community process. These were suggested edits by a user, *approved by user reviewers*, not mods. As the owner of the question you can refuse these edits or rollback to a previous version anytime. // And yes, "robo approved suggested edits" is a problem that SO is trying to address.

Comment: @EricD Yikes, I meant something like "community mods", just by their privilege. But thanks for the clarification about the whole process, especially about the possibility to refuse the changes! I did a manual rollback (a.k.a. typing). I do fully agreed about the "robo approving", editing/approving should only be done if someone is familiar with the technical terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `UIDocumentInteractionController` instead. With something like

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:"file://my.vcard"];
UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
[controller presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

This would have option to "Copy to Contacts"